# Xamarin "MagicGradients" package: how to reproduce XAML design in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, gradient

Basically what I am looking to do is reproduce this XAML gradient that I have designed in c# as multiple of this will need to be created by the codebehind based on data returned by a REST API.

**My XAML**

```
<magicgradients:GradientView>
      <magicgradients:GradientView.GradientSource>
            <magicgradients:LinearGradient Angle="0">
                  <magicgradients:GradientStop Color="#ED68A0" Offset="0" />
                  <magicgradients:GradientStop Color="#E01446" Offset="1" />
            </magicgradients:LinearGradient>
      </magicgradients:GradientView.GradientSource>
</magicgradients:GradientView>
```

**C# So Far**

```
LinearGradientBuilder Gradients = new GradientBuilder().AddLinearGradient(0).AddStop(Color.FromHex("#ED68A0"))
.AddStop(Color.FromHex("#E01446"));
```

`GradientView gradientView = new GradientView{ };`

The docs are a little vague and although I have opened a ticket on Github, I think it may be solved (to which I will close and update my ticket) faster on here

The package can be found on Github via [this](https://github.com/mgierlasinski/MagicGradients) link

The package can also be added to Xamarin Projects directly through NuGet by searching "Magic Gradients"

Comment: you can create a reusable ContentView in XAML and then create multiple copies from C#

Comment: @Jason The way the box is created and it's contents, colour and placement depend entirely on the results from the server. I can produce all of this logic pretty easily. I just need to know how to use this specific library to build the equivalent of the above XAML in C#, as their documentation only guides on how to create using XAML and the C# parts are vary vague

Comment: OK.  Suggestion - if you're asking about a specific third party library, it's a good idea to link to their project page so others are clear about which specific library you are using

Comment: @Jason Cheers, I've added a Github link and some more info so that it isn't such an ambiguous question. Hope this helps